# Warning: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, warnings

It seems like the `na.rm=T` within the `apply` function in my variance calculation:

> poolvarcheck=((7037*(apply(yes, 2, var, na.rm=T)))+(5394*(apply(no,2,var,na.rm=T))))/12431

is causing this warning message:

> "In if (na.rm) "na.or.complete" else "everything" :  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

I've looked around and this seems to mostly apply to loops or if clauses, but I'd like to know 1) whether this is affecting my results and how, and 2) if there is a way to avoid the warning.

Comment: What programming language? What program? Need more details!

Comment: Is it possible that you assigned something to a vector called `T` somewhere in your workspace? Even if you haven't, it's much better practice to always use `TRUE` and `FALSE` just in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `na.rm=TRUE`, chances are that you have redefined `T` and it is biting you. That's why use of `T`/`F` is strongly discouraged (and a package using those will fail the check).

Comment: Or I suppose one could be anal and use `1L` instead of "TRUE" :-)

Comment: Well, that won't work if the code checks for logical without casting ;) But you may find interesting bugs that way :P